# Sequence of Haskell's Random Generators

Tags: haskell, random

I'd like to write the following Haskell function that will provide me with a list of unique random generators:

```
randomGenerators :: RandomGen g => g -> [g]
```

Is the following a reasonable solution that won't create a situation where the "same" sequences are repeated?

```
randomGenerators g = iterate (fst . split) g
```

I am obviously throwing away half of all the generators but will this be a problem?

Comment: Erm. People will be happy to answer this question, but this seems like a really bad idea. What are you really trying to do? It may turn out there's a better way.

Answer (score 3):

This will work, providing that `split` is implemented correctly (that is, if it produces uncorrelated generators). The `System.Random` one is believed to be robust (although its implementation of `split` contains a comment `-- no statistical foundation for this!`, so use it at your own risk and test for correlations).

Alternatively, you can use a RNG specifically designed to be used in parallel batches. For example, I have a package [`Random123`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Random123) which implements [counter-based generators](http://dx.doi.org/doi:10.1145/2063384.2063405) (not very well optimized for performance right now, but may suit your purposes). There may be also bindings for [DCMT library](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/DC/dc.html) out there, or you can write your own.

Comment: Though it does come with some benefit, if someone can provide firm proof a bug in System.Random, I have a hard time believing it wouldn't be fixed promptly

Comment: @jozefg I don't think Bogdan is implying there's a bug. Just that nobody has any idea how `split` ought to behave! (Like, what guarantees should it give about how "different" its two returned generators are from each other? from the input?)

Comment: More accurately, there is a formal definition of independent RNGs, it's just that nobody has mathematically proved that the method used in ``stdSplit`` complies to this definition. It should be also possible to test this empirically, but I'm not aware of whether it has been done.